# How To Use CSS For JavaFX Projects

Tags: java, css, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I am quite new to JavaFX and was wondering if there is a way to assign a css file to the entire JavaFX project/scene.  Currently, I have to apply the stylesheet to every element I want to be styled with css.  I am working with IntelliJ and Scene Builder 2.0.  I have tried adding the stylesheets in my Main class, start method as shown below but it did not seem to have the desired effect.

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("JavaFXTest.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Test");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    root.getStylesheets().add("@../styling/styles.css");
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that it was a problem with the path to the css file.  I changed it to:

```
root.getStylesheets().add("styling/styles.css");
```

and achieved the desired results.  This way I do not need to manually add the stylesheet to every element in the UI, rather it works across the entire scene now.  Just declare your classes/id's as per normal css convention to add styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style sheet to the scene:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Hello World!"));

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/styling/styles.css");

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

In the above example the style sheet is located at `/styling/styles.css` relative to the source root.